# Comparing and Contrasting DNNClassifier and DNNLinearCombinedClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Tensorflow includes both a [DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier) and a [DNNLinearCombinedClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNLinearCombinedClassifier).  The DNNLinearCombinedClassifier implements a [network architecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.07792.pdf) from Google which incorporates both deep and shallow paths.

Of course, the DNNLinearCombinedClassifier can also be used without the shallow path, if configured properly. If we don't use the shallow path, is a DNLinearCombinedClassifier the same as a DNNClassifier, or are there other differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dense part of DNNLinearCombinedClassifier is exactly the same as a regular DNNClassifier.

Comment: I would upvote your answer, but I have no basis for evaluating it.